# On 'next' or 'previous' virtual keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, css, html

iOS5+ shows next/prev buttons above the keyboard:

[image]

Because they change the focused element on the page, they can cause issues with my single page app's layout. The 'tab' key on normal keyboards can cause similar issues, but I can slightly change its functionality to only cycle around the inputs I want with a custom `keydown` event.

Is there any way to do something similar for those buttons?

Comment: what issues are you having with using next key? if your page produces errors you probably have css issues. The only issue that causes layout issues is a fixed or absolute footer element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what your problem is.

My guess is that when you change focus with "Previous" and "next" button, something goes wrong with your design. And I'm also guessing that you click these when you are in an input (although it's pretty obvious).

When you change from an input to another (With tab key, using "previous/next"-buttons or by mouse), a blur event is triggered.

Now, you don't say what library, if any, you are using. But the fix is similar all around I would say.

if you use jQuery, do something similar to this:

```
//Selects all input elements, and binds a anonymous function to them. This function 
//is run when the blur event is triggered, meaning when we change focus to something else
 $("input").on("blur", function () { //Or live, depending on jQuery version

       //Your code here, that I assume you already have
    });
```